# LESS puts spaces in wrong places

Tags: css, less

So... I'am creating a small bootstrap and i want it efficiently done, so i've chose the LESS to do some job for me. And i found that LESS compiler puts spaces between classes when it is written like this:

```
div.cb {
  input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px #d9d9d9 solid;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 5px;

    .large {
      width: 250px;
    }

    .medium {
      width: 150px;
    }

    .small {
      width: 50px;
    }

    .fill {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

results in:

```
div.cb input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px #d9d9d9 solid;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}
div.cb input[type="text"] .large {
  width: 250px;
}
div.cb input[type="text"] .medium {
  width: 150px;
}
div.cb input[type="text"] .small {
  width: 50px;
}
div.cb input[type="text"] .fill {
  width: 100%;
}
```

and the gaps between the element and classes prevents in my browser (chrome) in the correct processing. Is there a way to have same or similar code in LESS and have right outputting CSS? Without those gaps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With less you can reference the parent of a code block by using `&`

So this:

```
.class
{
    .anotherClass 
    { 
        background: red; 
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.class .anotherClass { background: red; }
```

---

Whereas this:

```
.class
{
    &.anotherClass 
    { 
        background: red; 
    }
}
```

Compiles to this:

```
.class.anotherClass { background: red; }
```

I hope that makes the difference obvious

Comment: No worries :) `&` can be really useful in LESS